# criar link com download de arquivo

Tags: html

Galera crierai um link na meu site para o usuário poder baixar um arquivo.
O link funciona 100%, porém após o usuário clicar em baixar o arquivo e baixado para pasta download do computador. Como faço para o navegador abrir a janela perguntando qual o lugar para salvar o download?

Exemplo do link que eu criei.

```
<div onclick='document.location="Arquivos/arquivo.rm"'>Baixar</div>
```

O arquivo tem a extensão .rm

Comment: Tem como vc clicar com o botão direito do mouse no link e ir em "salvar como", a única maneira de você abrir a janela de diálogo para salvar em outra pasta é assim. Talvez vc consiga fazer um botão em javascript que ao ser clicado ele já abra a janela do *salvar como*. Só uma ideia!

Answer (score 4):

Hugo, por questões de segurança, você não pode fazer essa manipulação.

Para aparecer a opção de mostrar a janela onde o arquivo deve ser salvo, o usuário deve marcar essa opção nas configurações do navegador.

Por exemplo, no Chrome v53.0.2785.143 essa opção fica em Configurações, como mostra a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]